# What is the typical size of feature matrix for xgboost

Tags: feature-selection, boosting, subsampling

In other words, I have a binary classification problem with million samples and around 1000 features. I am trying to understand wheather I should subsample the dataset and add a feature selection step (and approximately how many features I should retain)

Comment: with a million samples, 1000 features is fine. No need for feature selection, since xgboost kind of takes care of that in the boosting framework.

Comment: Isn't 1000 features too much for tree based learning?  It takes a long time currently to train ...

Comment: If you feel it too slow, maybe you can try Lightgbm. Similar model to xgboost, but can be like 10 times faster

Answer (score 2):

The typical number of features is the number of features that you think are relevant. No more, no less.

It might be possible to tabulate the number of features used in every XGBoost model, and compute descriptive statistics of that data, but this is folly -- there's also an average telephone number, but no one's suggesting that you should call it.

People derive features and estimate models to solve particular problems. What does oncology have to do with the price of tea?